# What methodology to follow to find coordinates on a curved surface?

Tags: geometry, coordinates, coordinate-transformation, geometry-surface, projection-matrix

I have a trouble on finding the "coordinates on a curved surface" when I take a picture of it. Imagine a barrel or a curved surface, having n points on its surface and we need to determine their location. When the surface is photographed from '"front" and about 30 degrees rotated, the relative position of the points will look different.

If it was a flat plate, I would think to normalize the lengths and find the relative coordinate of each point. Since it is a flat plate, each of the normalized coordinates would give the same number independent pf the rotation angle. But when it is on a curved surface, that normalization does not help to find the coordinates. Is there a methodology to follow to be able to find the coordinates when the object is rotated?

A visual of an example problem could be seen here:
[image]

A top view of another example figure could be seen:
[image]

Comment: Do you know the maths of the surface? Do you have any data (e.g. the final color) that identifies a pixel of the surface related to its position before projecting?

Comment: First of all, how are you projecting the points from the surface onto the camera screen? Are you using orthogonal projection onto the plane of the screen? Or are you using the standard point-screen projection (projecting by drawing lines between a fixed point behind the screen and the points in 3D and looking at the lines' intersections with the plane of the screen)? Second, are your surface cylindrical, in the sense that it is the always same curve when you slice it, let's say, with a horizontal plane, and this curve is basically translated vertically, sweeping the surface?

Comment: Second, are you rotating the camera always around a fixed axis, running vertically? At least that's what it looks like on your pictures. And do you have the coordinates of the points on the screen for each camera shot? In particular, could we assume you know very well the parameters of the camera, like the distance between the point from which you are looking at the 3D world and the screnn (if relevant) and where the orthogonal projection of this point is onto the screen (usually it should be at the origin of the 2D coordinate system of the screen). Do you know the equation of the surface?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answers.

Unfortunately, this is going to be applied on real life objects for a measurement, which means I will not have the equation of the surface. I am thinking about taking pictures from far enough to have an almost orthogonal projection-like pictures and get rid of the effect of perspective. And with a fixed camera, object rotating around its axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are in the following situation: You have a fixed vertical line called `axis` which is the vertical rotation axis around which you rotate the surface. Furthermore, you have a plane `S`, representing the screen of your camera. The screen-plane `S` is also vertical, which is equivalent to the fact that it is parallel to the rotation `axis`. Then, the normal vector `N` of the screen-plane `S` points towards the `axis`.

We introduce a fixed coordinate system (it is called a camera-system, we see the world from the point of view of the camera and it is fixed because your camera is fixed) in the following way: we choose a fixed point `O` on the screen-plane `S` and draw the `O ---> y` axis on `S` as the unique line on `S` parallel to `axis` and passing through `O`. The axis `O ---> x` is the unique line perpendicular to the `O ---> y` axis and is thus horizontal. The normal vector `N` is aligned with the `O ---> z`-axis, which is also horizontal, starting from the camera and going through the `axis`, intersecting the latter orthogonally.

The coordinate system on the screen-plane, call it the screen-system, is simply the system obtained as `z = 0` (the orthogonal projection of the 3D points onto the screen `S`), i.e. it is the two-dimensional system `O x y` where the `O--->x` and `O--->y` axes of the screen-system are also axes of the camera-system, defined above.

From what I understand, you take photos of the surface twice, once in one position, then the second time after rotating it around the `axis` at an angle `a`. Take one of the marked points points `P` on the surface before rotation. Then it's orthogonal projection `p1` on the screen `S` has coordinates `[x1,y1]` in the screen0system. After rotation at an angle `a` of the surface around `axis` the point `P` now has orthogonal projection `p2` on the screen `S` with new coordinates `[x2,y2]` in the screen system. I assume you can determine the coordinates of any point on the screen with respect to the screen-system. If I am not wrong, the goal is equivalent to determining the coordinates of `P` before and after the rotation in three space `O x y z`. However, since your projection on the screen `S` is orthogonal, you simply need to determine the `z` coordinates of point `P` before and after the rotation. From there, you can go on to find the curvillinear coordinates of `P` on the surface, which could simply be the coordinates of the screen projected onto the surface, so the surface parametrization can be for example:

```
X = x1
Y = y1
Z = z1(x1, y1)
```

We are going to assume also that you know the distance `l` between the camera screen `S` and the rotation axis `axis`. I believe all of these assumtions, made up to now, are very reasonable, as you have control over setting up the camera (i.e. the screen plane `S` together with its coordinate system, which fairly natural) and the rotation axis `axis`. 
 The situation is as on the picture below:

[image]

As you can see, we have chosen the horizontal slice `y = y1` and due to the whole arrangement of the screen and camera coordinate systems, we have `y = y1 = y2`. Observe that because of the rotaion of the `axis`, we have `dist(P0, axis) = dist(Pa, axis)`. Therefore the triangle `P0 Pa axis` is isosceles with angle `a` at the vertex `axis`. So if you draw the axis of reflection symmetry of this triangle trough the vertex `axis`, you get two copies of the same right-angled triangle, in which you have the equation

```
dist(P0, Pa)/(2*dist(axis, P0)) = sin(a/2)
```

Combine this latter equation with the equation

```
dist(P0, axis) = dist(Pa, axis)
```

If you square both equations and put them together as one system, you get the system of two equation

```
dist(P0, Pa)^2 = 4*(dist(axis, P0))^2*(sin(a/2))^2

dist(P0, axis)^2 = dist(Pa, axis)^2
```

If you look at the three (right-angled) trapezoids `O p1 P0 axis` then `O p2 Pa axis`  and finally `P0 p1 p2 Pa` obtain the system of two quadratic equations of whose two unknowns are the z coordinates `z1` and `z2`. The rest of the parameters are given: `x1, x2, l, a`. You have to solve for `z1` and `z2`. There will be four pairs of solutions, you have to select the ones that correspond to the realistic situation. Solving the system exactly however might be difficult, so you can just use Newton's method to find a very good approximate solution.

I have written the system on the picture, you can see it in formulas. The angle `a` is your `theta`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dots on this cylinder have always the same distance to each other,you just have to figure out one of the coordinate triples and you can then calculate over the geodesic the other coordinates.

So it would be in geodetic coordination system:
(x1, y1, z1) 
(x1 + distance, y1, z1)
(x1 + 2*distance, y1, z1)

This only applies if the distance is constant between the coords and known and you know the angle of the geodesic ...

Comment: I think I can compare the angle of the object by comparing the width of them, by just taking acos(widthx/width1), as it works well for a flat plate.

The locations of the points are fixed, but the distance in between each other could be distance1 and distance2, which could be different in both x and y direction when looked at the 2D "photo" of the object.